# How I can check in my android app that, is microcontroller and firebase are connected or not?

Tags: android, firebase

I am controlling home appliances through android app, by sending 1 and 0 to firebase to on and off appliance respectively. I am facing an issue that if I operate any appliance through android app by sending 1 or o to firebase but if my controller side is not connected to internet and firebase, then How I can check internet connectivity of controller side ???

I want to check controller connectivity with firebase so that it show me some acknowledgment message in android app that your controller is connected with firebase and task is successful

Comment: Are you asking how to check if you Android app has an active connection to Firebase? If that's the case, and you're using the Firebase Realtime Database, have a look at the documentation on [detecting connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state).

Comment: no no sir. my firebase is connected to android App (at one side)  and microcontroller (Arduino at another side). I am okay with Android App and firebase connectivity. Now i want to monitor the connectivity between firebase and microcontroller in my Android app

Comment: I am remotely controlling home appliances and if i actuate any load by sending 1 and 0 to firebase and it's done successfully BUT if connection between firebase and micro controller is not established then how i will come to know that "There is no connection between them". How i can tackle this issue ?

Comment: That depends on *how* your micro-controller connects to Firebase. It'll be a lot easier to help if you show the code that you're asking for our input on. Also: if the Android side is working fine and you're not asking for our help there, your question probably not be tagged with `android`.